# Adding the quantities of products in a dataframe column in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the sum of weights in a column of an excel sheet that contains the product title with the help of Numpy/Pandas. I've already managed to load the sheet into a dataframe, and isolate the rows that contain the particular product that I'm looking for:

```
dframe = xlsfile.parse('Sheet1')
dfFent = dframe[dframe['Product:'].str.contains("ABC") == True]
```

But, I can't seem to find a way to sum up its weights, due to the obvious complexity of the problem (as shown below). For eg. if the column 'Product Title' contains values like -

- 1 gm ABC
- 98% pure 12 grams ABC
- 0.25 kg ABC Powder
- ABC 5gr

where, ABC is the product whose weight I'm looking to add up. Is there any way that I can add these weights all up to get a total of 268 gm. Any help or resources pointing to the solution would be highly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for values with units or percentage:

- `(?P<a>\d+\.\d+|\d+)` means extract float or int to column `a`
- `\s*` - is zero or more spaces between number and unit
- `(?P<b>[a-z%]+)` is extract lowercase unit or percentage after number to `b`

---

```
#add all possible units to dictonary
d = {'gm':1,'gr':1,'grams':1,'kg':1000,'%':.01}
df1 =  df['Product:'].str.extractall('(?P<a>\d+\.\d+|\d+)\s*(?P<b>[a-z%]+)')
print (df1)
            a      b
  match             
0 0         1     gm
1 0        98      %
  1        12  grams
2 0      0.25     kg
3 0         5     gr
```

Then convert first column to numeric and second map by `dictionary` of all units. Then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and multiple columns by [`prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html), last `sum`:

```
a = df1['a'].astype(float).mul(df1['b'].map(d)).unstack().prod(axis=1).sum()
print (a)
267.76
```

Similar solution:

```
a = df1['a'].astype(float).mul(df1['b'].map(d)).prod(level=0).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Is there a way that I can merge the rows 2 and 3 (98 % and 12 grams) => (0.98 x 12 grams)?

Comment: Hmm, not understand. multiplleying unit by percentage do `.prod(axis=1)`

Comment: So, ```dfWts['Qty'].astype(float).mul(dfWts['Unit'].map(d)).unstack().prod(axis=1)``` is the list of weights of all items?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if not percentage it not multiple in function `prod` (this function only multiple one column by another.)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on a different dataset, where it's only picking up % and not quantity units like kg, gm, mcg etc.! Has something changed in the `extractall()` method since then?

Comment: @harry04 - do you want extract only integer and floats? then use `df1 =  df['Product:'].str.extractall('(?P<a>\d+\.\d+|\d+)')`

Comment: Is there a way to modify this code so that a value like `100 g 95% pure ABC + 100 g FREE` gives the result `190` and not `9500` which is what I'm getting now.

Comment: @harry04 - You can add value to `dict` like `d = {'gm':1,'gr':1,'grams':1,'kg':1000,'%':.01}` to `d = {'gm':1,'gr':1,'grams':1,'kg':1000,'%':.01,'g':1}`

Comment: No I meant what should I do when I get 2 quantities that I need to add. For eg. `100 g 95% pure ABC + 100 g FREE` would mean adding `100 * 1 + 100 * 1` and then multiplying with `95 * 0.01` to get `190`. How can I do this?

Comment: @harry04 - It is really complicated, because is necessary correct assign number of weight to percentage. I think the best is create new question with all possible combination like `100 g 95% pure ABC + 100 g FREE`, maybe `100 g  pure ABC + 100 g 95%`, `+ data from question. Also is possible more `%` like `100 g  80% pure ABC + 100 g 95%` ?

Comment: Here's the modified question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516071/extracting-quantity-of-item-from-pandas-dataframe-column

Comment: @harry04 - Really hard, now I have no idea for some solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some data wrangling to get the column consistent in same format. You may do some matching and try to get `Product` column aligned and consistent, similar to date -time formatting.

Like you may do the following things.

- Make a separate column with only values(float)
- Change % value to decimal and multiply by quantity
- Replace value with `kg` to `grams`
- Without any string, only float column to get total.

Pandas can work well with this problem.

Note: There is no shortcut to this problem, you need to get rid of strings mixed with decimal values for calculation of sum.